# Join get 4 tables all result by id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

### Problem

Now I am doing edit form in codeigniter and I want to get all four tables data. From controller comes event_id and by this id I want to get data.

## Model

```
public function get_list_for_edit($event_id){
    return

   $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('events e')
            ->join('events_location el','el.events_id =' $event_id,'left')
            ->join('events_photos ep',
                    'ep.events_id =' $event_id,'left')
            ->join('push_notifications pn',
                    'pn.events_id =' $event_id,'left')
            ->where('e.event_id =' $event_id)
            ->row_object();
 }
```

### Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '$event_id' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: I'm merely a rookie, but is this syntax correct: `'...=' $event_id,'le...'`? As in, `'string' <space> $variable, 'string'`? Shouldn't there be a comma after the first string as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you need  string concatenation  (othewise the variable  in not correctly added  to the rest of the string)

```
  public function get_list_for_edit($event_id){
      return

     $this->db->select('*')
              ->from('events e')
              ->join('events_location el','el.events_id =' . $event_id,'left')
              ->join('events_photos ep',
                      'ep.events_id =' . $event_id,'left')
              ->join('push_notifications pn',
                      'pn.events_id ='. $event_id,'left')
              ->where('e.event_id =' . $event_id)
              ->row_object();
   }
```

for Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row_object()  error
You are not selecting table name    ... so you should  add the get('TABLE_NAME') method for the table/model you need

```
     $this->db->select('*')
              ->from('events e')
              ->join('events_location el','el.events_id =' . $event_id,'left')
              ->join('events_photos ep',
                      'ep.events_id =' . $event_id,'left')
              ->join('push_notifications pn',
                      'pn.events_id ='. $event_id,'left')
              ->where('e.event_id =' . $event_id)->get('TABLE_NAME')
              ->row_object();
```

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row_object()

Comment: @RavshanAbdurasulov   .. this mean that your error is resolved  but you have another one  ... answer  updated  ..

Comment: it is your query so  .. i don't know   ... i think the table related  to the model you need ..  could be event?

Comment: thank you sir! that is what i want! sorry for stupid question!

Comment: do not worry ... it happens to me too .. your question put me in a good mood